# How do I obtain the Battlefield 3 special operations camouflage?

Tags: battlefield-3

I want to know how I'm able to gain access to the black special operations camouflage/fatigue. Is it through levelling up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unlocked at [rank 42](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_unlockables_in_BF3_Multiplayer), Captain (alternate source: [ign](http://www.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-3/Ranks)) after `1,400,000` points.

Comment: Allright, thanx for the intel ;)

Answer (score 0):

By reaching the rank: 42(apparently). If you go to customization from the menus it lets you flip through all of camo's even if you don't have them. Flip to the end to see it. Note: You can't see unaquired unlocks from the in game menus. You have to be at the startup screen.

Comment: Thank you too, but the other was correct ;)